# Data sharing and communication between desktop applications

Tags: database-design, architecture

I need to support data sharing between desktop applications. I have three desktop applications **A, B, and C**. All three applications are planned to use together in a product life cycle. 
The workflow is as below.

    1. A user creates a design (say for example an image) using
    **application A**
    2. User opens
    **application B**
    and should be able to work on the design (created in
    **A**
    ) in order to add some effects on the created image.
    3. Similarly, the user should be able to continue working on the image in
    **application C**
    .

For this, I can use a database or file system to store the state of the process at all level. But the problem is, if a user opens the image in application **A and B** parallelly and do some changes in **A**, it should be reflected in **B** (if C opens, in C too).

Is there any other design or technology than file system/ database sharing between applications for this problem?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Kather

Answer (score 0):

Surely there are, how do you think Google Docs is implemented? Multiple users can mutate the same document and yet all the changes are there in real-time.

The key idea is to accumulate deltas (i.e. changesets) rather that change the source file directly. It implies existence of yet another - windowless - process responsible for 1) endless reading new deltas from all active sources, 2) merging them into a single resulting changeset and eventually 3) updating shared file.

`A`, `B` and `C` gonna be notified by the OS. That's an easy part. `Orchestrator` (windowless process) can be notified in different ways, among which are `stdin` or listening for a certain port on the `localhost`. It's up to you.

If you design your deltas carefully, you might get a `map/reduce`-able structure with all of its benefits.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by the previous answer it is possible.

You can use algorithms like [Conflict-free replicated data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type) and [Operational Transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) to do that. You can search for more information on the subject. There are a lot of whitepapers and articles on the subject.

Using deltas as mentioned in the previous answer is another thing you can do too. Google docs uses (at least the last time I checked) Operational Transformations.

Check this too. It's a nice visualization of OT: https://operational-transformation.github.io/visualization.html

You can use [IPC](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inter-process-communication/) to make both application talk to one another or use a third one as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. I will explore the topics which you mentioned here.